# How can I get Inset to use ImageScaled, but preserve aspect ratio?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

This code produces two identical images, despite the difference in the rectangles:

```
r1 = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];
r2 = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {0, 1}];
f[img_] := 
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{{t, 0, 0}, {0, t, 0}, {0, 0, t}}, {t, -1, 1}],
   Graphics3D[{Inset[
     Show[Graphics[img], ImageSize -> Large], {0.25, 0, 0}, Automatic,
      ImageScaled[0.25]]}]]
f[r1]
f[r2]
```

If I do `{Automatic,ImageScaled[0.25]}`, I am told that it should be a pair of numbers, or a scaled or offset form.

I want the height of the inset to be 25% of the overall graphic, and the width to be scaled accordingly.  I want it to work for any `img`, not just the two rectangles I gave; my actual use case involves .gif files.  How do I make it so that `f[r1]` and `f[r2]` show different insets, i.e., inset the rectangles shown by `Show[r1]` and `Show[r2]`, with the height scaled to 25% of the total height of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what the output should look like, but I think part of the problem lies in the way you have described `Inset`, from the documentation:

> represents an object obj inset **in a graphic**.

Note that your code does not have a graphic into which your Inset is, well, inset.

If we redefine `f`:

```
f[img_] := 
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{{t, 0, 0}, {0, t, 0}, {0, 0, t}}, {t, -1, 1}],
   Epilog -> {Inset[
     Show[Graphics[img], ImageSize -> Large], {0.5, 0.5}, Automatic, 
     ImageScaled[0.25]]}]
```

We now get a plot that is at least responsive to the different shapes of `r1` and `r2`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I needed to change your {0,0,0} to {0.5,0.5} because `Epilog` expects `Graphics` not `Graphics3D` and `Inset` is expected scaled coordinates, so the center of the image is {0.5,0.5}.  `ImageScaled[...]` can be manipulated to change the relative size of the inset and I think what you're left with now is tweaking these parameters to get the image where you want on the plot.

Answer (score 2):

See if this will work.  It should, since you can get the `ImageDimensions` of an imported GIF.  **Note**: I changed `r1`, `r2` to `Graphics`.  You can apply `f` to `Graphics` or to `Image`.

```
r1 = Graphics@Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];
r2 = Graphics@Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {0, 1}];
f[img_] := 
  With[{g = ParametricPlot3D[{{t, 0, 0}, {0, t, 0}, {0, 0, t}}, {t, -1, 1}]},
    Show[
     g,
     Graphics3D[{
       Inset[img, {0.25, 0, 0}, Automatic, 
        ImageScaled[ 0.25 #/Last[#] &[ImageDimensions[img]/ImageDimensions[g]] ]
        ]}
      ]]
   ];
f[r1]
f[r2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Caveat**:  `ImageScaled` depends on the dimensions of the enclosing image.  They can change if the output of `f` is displayed with other things. For instance, I'm not sure how to handle `{f[r1], f[r2]}`.  Perhaps one could scale by `ImageDimensions@Rasterize[{f[r1], f[r2]}]`, but you'd have to know those dimensions before `f` was executed.